# Expression that means "Ruin something by publicizing it"?

Tags: expressions

I was wondering if there is a colloquialism or phrase for when you ruin something by documenting it or publicizing it.

For example, if a journalist were to do a story on a beautiful, lush, undeveloped region, and the buzz created by the story resulted in a bunch of ugly hotels and vacation homes being built there, thereby ruining the natural beauty of the area.

That is just one example though. It could be ruining anything, not just nature. It would be like a combination of "shouting it from the rooftops" and "blowing its cover".

Comment: All right, but let sleeping dogs lie.

Comment: Only remotely related, but hilarious: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/86jmih/what_was_ruined_because_too_many_people_started/dw5k6o0/

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily 'by publicising it' but something can become `A victim of its own success' when its popularity or success ends up having negative side-effects.

e.g. "The national park is always overcrowded, it's a victim of its own success"

Here's an article using it in exactly the context you describe https://connachttribune.ie/tourism-trail-may-be-victim-of-its-own-success-532/

Definition: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-become-a-victim-of-its-own-success

Answer (score 1):

**Nobody goes there anymore. It’s too crowded.**.

This is often attributed to [Yogi Berra](https://en.m.wikiquote.org/wiki/Yogi_Berra), although Wikiquotes says that it’s a misattribution.

Still, if you want to strike a lighter tone, you can’t go wrong with a Yogi-ism. In effect, you connect your writing with a whole world of human absurdity that’s well known to American readers and probably world-wide.

Comment: See also, my comment at OP.